Why is the value from the input immediately displayed? How to fix it?
Why is the value I enter into the input field immediately displayed, instead of appearing after I click the add button?"
The issue is that inputValue is being immediately bound to the app-new-todo component via two-way binding using [(ngModel)]="inputValue". As a result, the entered value is displayed as soon as the user types into the input field. I would like it to only appear after clicking the "ADD" button.
How can I adjust the code to prevent the immediate display and ensure that the task only shows up after the button click?
Here is code:
  export interface TodoData {
  id: number;
  todo: string;
  done: boolean;
}
export class TodoComponent {
  @Output() todo = new EventEmitter<TodoData>();
  inputValue = '';
  done = false;

  addTask() {
    this.todo.emit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      todo: this.inputValue,
      done: this.done,
    });
  }
}

HTML:
<section>
  <form (ngSubmit)="addTask()">
    <div>
      <input
        name="todo"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter new task"
        [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
      />
      <button>ADD</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <app-new-todo [task]="inputValue" />
</section>


export class AppComponent {
  onAddTask(data: { id: number; todo: string; done: boolean }) {
    console.log(data.todo);
  }
}

HTML: 
<app-header />
<app-todo (todo)="onAddTask($event)" />

export class NewTodoComponent {
  @Input({ required: true }) task!: string;
}

HTML:
<div>
  <h1>{{ task }}</h1>
</div>




You are using two-way data binding which updates the property immediately.
The sample project is managed on Stackblitz.
File: todo.component.html
<div *ngIf="task">
  <!-- Only display if task is not empty -->
  <h1>{{ task }}</h1>
</div>


File: todo.component.ts
@Input({ required: true }) task!: string;

File: new-todo.component.html
<section>
  <form (ngSubmit)="addTask()">
    <div>
      <input
        name="todo"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter new task"
        [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
      />
      <button type="submit">ADD</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>

File: new-todo.component.ts
export class NewTodoComponent {
  @Output() todo = new EventEmitter<TodoData>();
  inputValue = '';
  done = false;

  addTask() {
    // Emit the todo task only when Add button is clicked
    this.todo.emit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      todo: this.inputValue,
      done: this.done,
    });
    // Optionally clear the input field after adding the task
    this.inputValue = '';
  }
}

export interface TodoData {
  id: number;
  todo: string;
  done: boolean;
}

app.component.html
<app-todo [task]="taskToDisplay"></app-todo>
<app-new-todo (todo)="onAddTask($event)"></app-new-todo>

app.component.ts
taskToDisplay: string = '';

onAddTask(data: TodoData) {
  // Set the task to be passed to the new-todo component
  this.taskToDisplay = data.todo;
  console.log(data.todo);
}

NOTE: Don't forget to add the necessary imports

Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not only on a third-party site.

@HereticMonkey removed the third party*

This also work as an solution. Thank you <ˇ3

You have to use two variables, inputValue for storing the typed value and todoInput for passing the data to the child component.
<section>
  <form (ngSubmit)="addTask()" #form="ngForm">
    <div>
      <input
        name="todo"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter new task"
        [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
      />
      <button>ADD</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <app-new-todo [task]="todoInput" />
</section>

and in TS on submit action you update the todoInput value.
addTask() {
  this.todoInput = this.inputValue;
  this.todo.emit({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    todo: this.todoInput,
    done: this.done,
  });
  this.inputValue = '';
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export interface TodoData {
  id: number;
  todo: string;
  done: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-todo',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>{{ task }}</h1>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class NewTodoComponent {
  @Input({ required: true }) task!: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, NewTodoComponent],
  template: `
    <section>
      <form (ngSubmit)="addTask()" #form="ngForm">
        <div>
          <input
            name="todo"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter new task"
            [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
          />
          <button>ADD</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <app-new-todo [task]="todoInput" />
    </section>
  `,
})
export class TodoComponent {
  @Output() todo = new EventEmitter<TodoData>();
  inputValue = '';
  done = false;
  todoInput = '';

  addTask() {
    this.todoInput = this.inputValue;
    this.todo.emit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      todo: this.todoInput,
      done: this.done,
    });
    this.inputValue = '';
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TodoComponent],
  template: `
    <app-todo (todo)="onAddTask($event)" />
  `,
})
export class App {
  onAddTask(data: { id: number; todo: string; done: boolean }) {
    console.log(data.todo);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Wouldn't it be better to one-way bind instead of two-way if you'll store two variables and update the real value once  <button (click)="addTask()"> clicked

@TalhaAkca When you submit usually you reset the input field. so by resetting the todo component input also becomes empty, that is why I am going for two property approach

Working fine now! Thank you guys <3
